# React Redux and Input's onChange

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm dealing with many fields on one page, some of them are connected, some of them are not. You can simple imagine it as a Page with fields, or something like this. I know there is two ways of handling the state of the input(storing its value):

1. storing inside the Redux's store
2. saving in local state and then dispatch it to the Redux's store on some event(like save button)

I really like the way of Redux and how it handle things and its single source of truth, but the thing is that if I do go with the first approach, I will need to dispatch an action every single time I change a key in input field. Is this me or does it really looks insane? To set a single input, I will need to dispatch around 50-100 times. What if this a longer message, like some post's textarea field?

I thought of throttling or debouncing, but really don't want to make it this way.

Can you please suggest something? Thanks

Comment: `To set a single input, I will need to dispatch around 50-100 times` Why?

Comment: @ShivamJha well, because I will handle onChange on single key input. A simple heading for this post(React Redux and Input's onChange) is 32 keys and that's without fixing misspelling :) so for a simple heading, I will need around 50-60 on average dispatches

Comment: You can use react state for single input's state, and then for setting Page's state use Redux

Comment: #2 is [the official recommendation](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#avoid-putting-form-state-in-redux)

Comment: @ShivamJha I know, I've mentioned it in my post, but thanks for your help

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks a lot for the reference to the off. docs. I missed this somehow. Even though it says "In most use cases", I wanna just clarify something with you as you seems to be knowledgeable in the react and redux: if I have some inputs that involve conditional importing of other components? So to say, the form input have a global influence and other components are depend on that. Should I go with the first approach then? Because otherwise it will be very UX unfriendly

Comment: @triadontus If the value of the input is needed by other components in your application (shared state) then I'd store them in Redux. Dispatching many actions should not be a problem if you use pure components and not re render everything that doesn't need to be re rendered. I would not advise storing the value in local state **and** redux state, redux state should be enough.

Comment: @HMR Thanks, but doesn't it will lead to over-cached-data in the Redux's store? Because as I can tell, react-redux does use immer under the hood. So, for example, when I type in the input "Hello world", does react-redux will store under the hood also the "Hello worl" and all the previous values of "Hello world"?

Comment: @triadontus If multiple components need the values of your inputs then you can raise the state with the possible negative consequences of needing to prop drill. You can use React.context or you can use Redux. Either raised local state, context or redux they all remember their previous state so that is no reason to use one over the other. With react-redux and reselect you do have extra memoized values but they enable you to target re renders better. Redux does not store **all** the previous values, only the devtools do in develop mode.